# How do I obtain a checksum for a Taproot descriptor so that I can import it using importmulti?

Tags: taproot, output-script-descriptors, checksum

I tried to import an [example](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md#examples) Taproot descriptor using `bitcoin-cli importmulti`

`tr(c6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5,{pk(fff97bd5755eeea420453a14355235d382f6472f8568a18b2f057a1460297556),pk(e493dbf1c10d80f3581e4904930b1404cc6c13900ee0758474fa94abe8c4cd13)})`

I got the error "Missing checksum". How do I generate the checksum and where do I append it to the descriptor?

A checksum was added to descriptors in this [PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15368).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the checksum using:

`bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo insert_descriptor_here`.

This outputs the descriptor with the checksum appended at the end under "descriptor" and a separate "checksum" field with the checksum on its own.

```
{
  "descriptor": "tr(c6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5,{pk(fff97bd5755eeea420453a14355235d382f6472f8568a18b2f057a1460297556),pk(e493dbf1c10d80f3581e4904930b1404cc6c13900ee0758474fa94abe8c4cd13)})#2rqrdjrh",
  "checksum": "2rqrdjrh",
  "isrange": false,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

You can then use `bitcoin-cli importmulti` on that descriptor.

More guidance is in the [descriptor doc](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md#checksums).

Thanks to darosior for answering this on IRC.

Comment: As an aside, I think that if you call `getdescriptorinfo` on a descriptor that contains a privkey, it will return the descriptor with the corresponding pubkey in the `descriptor` field. But the checksum verifies this modified descriptor, not the one you passed (with privkey). The checksum for the descriptor containing the privkey would be in the `checksum` field.

I was confused by that at first (and is still very confused by descriptors so far).